# Count all row in union with pagination (OFFSET,FETCH)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Here is my query.

```
 SELECT 
         S.Id,
         S.[Order],
         COUNT(*) OVER () AS Total_Count --Return 4
FROM Subscriptions S
UNION 
SELECT 
         S1.Id,
         S1.[Order],
         COUNT(*) OVER () AS Total_Count --return 5
FROM Subscriptions1 S1
ORDER BY [Order] DESC
            OFFSET 0 ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
```

What I want is count 9 (4+5) in every row.

Answer (score 4):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT id, [Order], COUNT(*) OVER () AS Total_Count
FROM ((SELECT S.Id, S.[Order],
       FROM Subscriptions S
      ) UNION 
      (SELECT S1.Id, S1.[Order]
       FROM Subscriptions1 S1
      )
     ) s
ORDER BY [Order] DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

Note:  Only use `UNION` if you want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.  Otherwise, use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I have 30 column in each table which I have in select statement.

Comment: And I think '((SELECT S.Id, S.[Order],
       FROM Subscriptions S
      ) UNION 
      (SELECT S1.Id, S1.[Order]
       FROM Subscriptions1 S1
      )
     )'  will take more time because it does not have offset and fetch. it will fetch all records.

Comment: @abh . . . Not really.  Your original query is reading all the data and then removing duplicates.  A lot of work is already happening.